# How to remove Noise from the buzzer?

Tags: noise, buzzer

[image: Circuit Diagram]

It is a simple water level indicator using BC547 and a buzzer. It works on a 9v/12v battery.
Its switch is placed beside the motor pump's switch. Whenever the motor switch is on there is a noise observed in the buzzer. (There is no noise when the motor switch is in off position)

What could be the reason and how to eliminate it  ?

[image: Switches]

Comment: Separate the wirings farther apart. Add some shielding. Twist the *related* wires.

Comment: Noise as in sound or noise as in EMI? This is an electronics site so we always assume the latter unless you explicitly say otherwise. Check the description of the noise tag.

Comment: @Lundin I'd guess it's EMI causing audible noise from the buzzer.

Comment: There is no pull down resistor on the transistor base.  With a low water level, the transistor may partially switch on due to electrical noise and cause unexpected results.

Comment: If the water tank is metal then it should connect to the circuit ground. a shielded audio cable should connect the transistor input. Of course the transistor needs a base to emitter resistor.

Comment: A by pass capacitor has served the purpose. It is connected between base and emitter of BC547 transistor